# Idea. How to import code_scheme from external file?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import, formatting, checkstyle

I have following file inside my project.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <code_scheme name="code-style-idea">
      <option name="RIGHT_MARGIN" value="100" />
      <codeStyleSettings language="JAVA">
        <option name="KEEP_FIRST_COLUMN_COMMENT" value="false" />
        <option name="KEEP_BLANK_LINES_IN_DECLARATIONS" value="1" />
        <option name="KEEP_BLANK_LINES_IN_CODE" value="1" />
        <option name="KEEP_BLANK_LINES_BEFORE_RBRACE" value="1" />
        <option name="BLANK_LINES_AFTER_IMPORTS" value="2" />
        <option name="BLANK_LINES_AROUND_FIELD" value="1" />
        <option name="BLANK_LINES_AFTER_CLASS_HEADER" value="1" />
        <option name="BLANK_LINES_AFTER_ANONYMOUS_CLASS_HEADER" value="1" />
        <option name="INDENT_CASE_FROM_SWITCH" value="false" />
        <option name="ALIGN_MULTILINE_PARAMETERS" value="false" />
        <option name="ALIGN_MULTILINE_RESOURCES" value="false" />
        <option name="SPACE_WITHIN_ARRAY_INITIALIZER_BRACES" value="true" />
        <option name="SPACE_BEFORE_ARRAY_INITIALIZER_LBRACE" value="true" />
        <option name="CALL_PARAMETERS_WRAP" value="1" />
        <option name="METHOD_PARAMETERS_WRAP" value="1" />
        <option name="RESOURCE_LIST_WRAP" value="5" />
        <option name="EXTENDS_LIST_WRAP" value="1" />
        <option name="THROWS_LIST_WRAP" value="1" />
        <option name="EXTENDS_KEYWORD_WRAP" value="1" />
        <option name="THROWS_KEYWORD_WRAP" value="1" />
        <option name="METHOD_CALL_CHAIN_WRAP" value="1" />
        <option name="BINARY_OPERATION_WRAP" value="1" />
        <option name="BINARY_OPERATION_SIGN_ON_NEXT_LINE" value="true" />
        <option name="TERNARY_OPERATION_WRAP" value="5" />
        <option name="ARRAY_INITIALIZER_WRAP" value="1" />
        <option name="METHOD_ANNOTATION_WRAP" value="0" />
        <option name="CLASS_ANNOTATION_WRAP" value="0" />
        <option name="FIELD_ANNOTATION_WRAP" value="0" />
        <indentOptions>
          <option name="USE_TAB_CHARACTER" value="true" />
        </indentOptions>
      </codeStyleSettings>
    </code_scheme>
```

How to apply this file for my current project opened in idea?

my efforts:

[image]

if I click to `Manage...`:

[image]

If I click `set from...`:
[image]

Thus I don't see where can I select external file with configuration. please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Save your current project as folder-based project you should have `.idea` folder.
2. Replace content of `.idea/codeStyleSettings.xml` with your settings.

Answer (score 1):

I could not make the other solution work for Intellij IDEA 15.

I had to create a code scheme with the same name (let's say `{your_code_scheme}`):

`File > Other settings > Default settings` and then select `Manage...` after "code scheme" dropdown and `Save as`.

Then, the last step consists in replacing the newly created file in `~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea15/codestyles/{your_code_scheme}.xml` by the correct one.